# PHP file to check if email exists in database

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I`m trying to check if an email already exists in my database, I thought I had the right code to check, but for some reason, I can still create another user with the same email. I want to check for both, username and email.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
<?php
  if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdcheck)){
    header("Location: ../cadastrar.php?error=emptyfields&nome=".$username."&email=".$email);
    exit();
  }else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)){
    header("Location: ../cadastrar.php?error=invalidmailusername");
    exit();
  }else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    header("Location: ../cadastrar.php?error=invalidmail&nome=".$username);
    exit();
  }else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)){
    header("Location: ../cadastrar.php?error=invalidusername&email=".$email);
    exit();
  }else if($pwd !== $pwdcheck){
    header("Location: ../cadastrar.php?error=passwordcheck&email=".$email."&nome=".$username);
    exit();
  }else{
    $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM users WHERE usuario=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
      header("Location: ../cadastrar.php?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }else{
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
      if ($resultCheck > 0){
        header("Location: ../cadastrar.php?error=usertaken&email=".$email);
        exit();
      }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (nomecompleto ,usuario, emailuser, pwdusers) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
          header("Location: ../cadastrar.php?error=sqlerror");
          exit();
        }else{
          $hashedpwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $nomecompleto, $username, $email , $hashedpwd);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          header("Location: ../cadastrar.php?cadastro=sucesso");
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  mysqli_close($conn);
}else{
  header("Location: ../cadastrar.php");
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should replace `usuario=?` in `$sql = "SELECT usuario FROM users WHERE usuario=?";` for `emailuser=?` and replace the bind value to `$email`. You are currently not checking for email, instead you are checking for name.

Comment: I want to check for both

Comment: Use `"SELECT usuario, emailuser FROM users WHERE usuario=? AND emailuser=?"` and the bind `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);`. That way you are checking that both items are used. Note that you can still have the same email with different username (John and Paul can register the same email since the users didn't matched). To check for the values individually and avoid that, replace the `AND` for `OR` in the query.

Comment: It worked, thank you!